# Multiple OR ( || ) And One && In if statement

Tags: php, mysql

Will It Work ? I want To send email through chron job. Current Code with only OR (||) is working perfectly. Now I want to add one AND (&&) in this statement. Here $fullDays have OR statemet + I Need To check For pay_confirm column should contain "0".

Will It Work ?

Code is -

```
$date1= date("Y-m-d");
$date2=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateexpire['expiry_date']));
$dateDiff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));

if (($fullDays =="7" || $fullDays =="6" || $fullDays =="5" || $fullDays =="4" || $fullDays =="3" || $fullDays =="2" || $fullDays =="1" || $fullDays =="0") && ($dateexpire["payment_confim"]=="0")){
    ob_start();
```

Comment: Your code will definitely work. You got issues? Have you tested it?

Comment: basically, i am using previous code (with only ||) since last one year. But added && just Today. To check whether it is working or not, I have to make some changes in database...which is somehow complicated for me as database is too large and contains vital info. So I am asking this question.

Comment: dont really see any problems with this code, if the database is large, you can use memcached for the large data sets , and for the email you can use mail queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best would have been if you tried it out by yourself. Yes it will work. Your if statement is a bit messy though and it's not very efficient to check for every single value like you do. It's not very maintainable and prone to errors. If you feel that an if statement gets messy there's most probably a cleaner and easier way to do it.

```
$days = range(0,7);

if ( in_array($fullDays, $days) && $dateexpire["payment_confim"] == "0" ){
    ob_start();
```

That'll make your live a lot easier. But yours will work too of course. If you are uncertain read up again how booleans evaluate. That's absolutely essential for survival.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try with your solution and will let u know...thanx once again

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will work just fine, but it works pretty complicated:

```
if($banana == 1&&$pear == 2||$mango == 7&& $strawberry == 3)
{
// if code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

However, normally there's no point in asking a question on here unless you actually have a problem.

If you were concerned about sending a bad email out to subscribers, you should be testing new code on a separate server that can't email any clients by mistake. That way, even if there is a problem with the code there's no way no one will ever know and you can just fix it without worry.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will definitely work. Seems like you're troubled for testing your code. As a developer, you need to handle the situation easily by using **dummy** data for testing.You can just declare `$fullDays` and `$dateexpire["payment_confim"]` and assign values like:

```
/*
$date1= date("Y-m-d");
$date2=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateexpire['expiry_date']));
$dateDiff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));

*/
 //for testing, assign test value in the variable $fullDays and array $dateexpire["payment_confim"]
    $fullDays = 5;
    $dateexpire["payment_confim"] = 0;
    if (($fullDays =="7" || $fullDays =="6" || $fullDays =="5" || $fullDays =="4" || $fullDays =="3" || $fullDays =="2" || $fullDays =="1" || $fullDays =="0") && ($dateexpire["payment_confim"]=="0")){
        //ob_start(); 
        echo "Conditions met";
     }
     else
     {
      echo "Conditions not met";
     }
```